# slave mysql configuration is not stored

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication, ssh

**EDIT**
It seems that the problem is with my SSH connection, so I created a different question on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/905433/set-up-master-slave-over-ssh-and-port-pipe-for-a-mysql-replication). From what I understand so far, it that this problem is caused from the fact that the port forwarding is not established properly.

***Original question***
I am trying to create a master-slave sync between two Mysql instances. After a lot of work, I at least have two running servers (since I had so many problems that most of the times I was breaking something). 
Now, on my slave my.cnf file I have

> server-id               = 155
>   log_bin                 =
>   /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
>   master-host = 127.0.0.1
>   master-user =
>   masterUser
>   master-password = masterpassword
>   master-port = 3336
>   (I am using port forwarding, so that why I use 127.0.0.1 as host)

The problem is that when I ask for the slave's id I get 0

```
mysqld --help --verbose |grep server-id
```

> replicate-same-server-id                          FALSE
>   server-id                                         0

and

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';
```

> +---------------+-------+
>   | Variable_name | Value |
>   +---------------+-------+
>   | server_id     | 0     |
>   +---------------+-------+

The file I am using is the proper file, since when I added this

> [mysqld]
>   collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
>   init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
>   character-set-server = utf8

the result of  `mysqld --help --verbose |grep character-set-server`
changed from

> character-set-server                              latin1

to

> character-set-server                              utf8

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out one of my problems was that  I was reading the wrong documentation. The guide I was following was for an older version of mysql.
for the current version the settings for the master are not entered inside the configuration file but using a mysql command

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST="127.0.0.1", MASTER_USER='user', MASTER_PASSWORD='password', MASTER_LOG_FLIE='mysql-bin.000080', MASTER_LOG_POS=107, MASTER_PORT=7777;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- Have you restarted the MySQL instance after setting the `server-id` variable in `my.cnf`? (Obvious, I know, but I have to ask!)
- In which section of the `my.cnf` file have you added this variable? The `[mysqld]` section would be an appropriate place for it, I think.
- Do you have any other .cnf files that might overwrite your setting? Assuming Linux, a command such as `mysqld --help --verbose | head -n 20` should give you some output which includes the files where mysqld is looking for default settings.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am out of the office due to local holiday, so don't have the all t answers but I can tell you that I do restart msql, as I stated on my question I do have the [mysqld] section over my options and that I used some command, that I don't remember now, to find all configuration files. All we empty except the one I am editing. Also prior to this problem while I was editing these settings mysqld failed to start, so settings where read by mysql